# Display username on user's page

Tags: django-templates

I wanna display user's name on his page. {{user.username}} / {{user.pk}} give me the name or id of the user, authorized at the current moment, but not those, who's page it is. What do I have to write in a template instead of {{user.username}}?
urls.py

```
url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', 'user'),
```

views.py

```
def user(request, user_id):
context_instance=RequestContext(request)
user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
return render_to_response('user.html',
                          {'var': 'value'},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just pass the user object to your template.

```
def user(request, user_id):

    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    return render_to_response('user.html',
                      {'user': user,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

then in your template.

```
{{user.username}}  / {{user.pk}}
```

Comment: Thank you, but you misunderstood the question. I don't want authorized user's name, I want name of the user, whose page it is. For example, on page "../user/12/" in title I wanna see "user #12's page" and his nickname.

Comment: Many thanks, it works! But is it possible to display both of them on the same page, because now I cannot show the authorized user ?

Comment: yes, now just use `{{request.user.username}}` for the currently authenticated user in your template, you can have both at the same time, nothing wrong with that.